# CSS not being applied to input element

Tags: html, css

This is weird, I cannot see the problem, and I have some experience using CSS.

```
input {
  border: solid 1px #0066FF;
}
.docDataEditorRow input {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="docDataEditor">
    <form>
        <div class="column-50">
        <div class="docDataEditorRow">
            <label for="keyword-Fecha">Fecha</label>
            <input type="text" value="20131122" id="keyword-Fecha">
        </div>
        <div class="docDataEditorRow">
            <label for="keyword-Fecha de Creacion">Fecha de Creacion</label>
            <input type="text" value="2013-11-22 00:00:00" id="keyword-Fecha de Creacion">
        </div>      
        </div>
 <div class="column-50"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

But only the first `input` class is being applied.

The problem:

```
.docDataEditorRow input {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Is not being appliend or shown in Firebug as overriden

Comment: It is working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/n4R3Z/

Comment: Could you tell me please what's wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/bb44J/

Comment: Ive added what is wrong

Comment: Did you tried a more accurate targeting to the elements? Something like ´#docDataEditor form .docDataEditorRow input´

Comment: You need to provide code that actually reproduces the problem. Check this with testing it using the *exact* code you post and nothing else. Also specify the browser(s) tested (including version number and platform).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n4R3Z/2/

Comment: FYI spaces aren't allowed in `id` attributes http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Having looked at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4R3Z/2/), there was an invalid character in the CSS.  This was causing it to break and not apply and styles after this character.

Once removed the styles apply correctly

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4R3Z/3/)

---

#### original answer

The easiest way to resolve this is to use a class name instead of the element (`input`).

```
<input class="bacon" type="text" value="20131122" id="keyword-Fecha">

.bacon {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Using `.docDataEditorRow input` can be dangerous as you start to make your CSS specific.  Keeping things to a single classname will make your css much more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: First check in your dev tools the css styles exist in the stylesheet correctly.  Then use your dev tools to see what other styles are applied to that element.

Comment: I've added it, and strangely it doesn't work either. I am totally lost. .editorInput {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

Comment: ok, inspect element using your browser dev tools and see what styles are applied to the input element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n4R3Z/2/

Comment: You had a strange character in the css which was breaking it.  I have removed it and it now works http://jsfiddle.net/n4R3Z/3/

Comment: Well that was very WEIRD, phpstorm showed NOTHING there, not even a SPACE (middle dot). But when I put the cursor there it was like an invisible character. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which invalid character where?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If you go to the fiddle, at the bottom of the css just above the class `editorInput` there is a red dot.  That is the invalid character.  Remove that an the following style will be applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may have something overriding it. Is the rule showing in the element inspector?

I'd try the following:

```
#docDataEditor .docDataEditorRow input[type="text] {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Still not working, the content to be styled is inside a div that is generated automatically by JQuery, if that helps. Its so strange

Comment: And what are you seeing in the element inspector?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n4R3Z/2/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AJSkh/

Your code is exactly as you have pasted it in your question, and it is working as expected...

maybe you have something else in your code that is causing it to not work.

```
input {
  border: solid 1px #0066FF;
}
.docDataEditorRow input {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

<div id="docDataEditor">
    <form>
        <div class="column-50">
        <div class="docDataEditorRow">
            <label for="keyword-Fecha">Fecha</label>
            <input type="text" value="20131122" id="keyword-Fecha">
        </div>
        <div class="docDataEditorRow">
            <label for="keyword-Fecha de Creacion">Fecha de Creacion</label>
            <input type="text" value="2013-11-22 00:00:00" id="keyword-Fecha de Creacion">
        </div>      
        </div>
 <div class="column-50"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n4R3Z/2/